# Дети чиновников. Корректна ли формулировка?

Tags: грамотная-речь, значение-слов

Является ли корректной формулировка "дети чиновников"?
Речь идёт о детях, лишившихся родителей, но важно подчеркнуть, что умершие родители были именно чиновниками.

Answer (score 2):

> Дети чиновников

Формально говоря, относится к любому человеку, чьи родители когда-либо были чиновниками. (Вспомните привычное "сын врага народа". Если "враг народа" умирал, клеймо не снималось.) Однако без дополнительных пояснений скорее всего будет воспринято читателем как "дети действующих чинивников".

Все станет на свои места, если сказать "осиротевшие дети чиновников".

Answer (score 1):

Само по себе выражение корректно. Но если важно, что эти дети — сироты, а из контекста это не следует, то собеседник или читатель сделать такой вывод самостоятельно не сможет.

Answer (score 0):

Из данной формулировки ясно одно: родителями детей являются чиновники, а не то, что дети лишились родителей-чиновников.